# How to trigger scavenger hunt upgrade diagram quests?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I know that the scavenger hunt quests are triggered when you buy the treasure map for the relevant one. And there are upgrades for the gears you get from these quests. But how do you trigger the quests for upgrade diagrams? To be more specific, for example I have the quest for wolf school gear and part 2 of its upgrades. How do I activate the other part quests for it? Should I buy something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are maps for all of the upgrades which you can buy from various sellers across the world.

For the Wolf school the sellers are in Novigrad and Kaer Trolde. You will need to have progressed sufficiently in the main quests to get some of these.

You can also find the diagrams by just exploring.

Comment: So you confirm that upgrade quests should be triggered by separate maps?

Comment: Yes, a map for each one.

Comment: Okay, but how does the first map activate the original quest **and the part 2 quest** ?

Comment: If you stumble across a diagram it unlocks that quest part. Also, I think, if you have just the stub, you can carry out the task to get the other quests for that  gear level/set

Comment: @PingQueen you just need to read it I think. Then do the first task and the other parts unlock (I think) if you've not unlocked it through other means (other maps or just stumbling across a diagram)

Comment: As soon as I downloaded the dlc for that quest line, I bought the map from Lindenvale's blacksmith and they both got added to my journal. As far as I know wolf school gear is only in Kaer Morhen area. I've not progressed that far in main story to get there, so it's impossible for me to stumble upon one of the diagrams. Also, I double checked, I don't have anything regarding that gear in crafting menu.